# Formulating an optimization problem with non linear constraints

Tags: constraints, scheduling, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to solve a dynamic machine scheduling problem using what I think qualifies as a non linear programming constraints.

I have academic knowledge of linear programming techniques and appreciate the opportunity to try my hands at non linear programming.

However, before anything  I am struggling to write down a well forumulated problem. Here is the situation:

- I have a list of tasks of various natures that are ordered by "degree of emergency"
- Several machines, that specialize in various tasks, work on those tasks based on the "degree of emergency" and their specialty
- Tasks are not preemptive (start one, finish it, no interruption)
- Completion time is statistically known based on the nature of the task and the machine assigned to it.
- All machines should be used with minimal downtime
- Workload is balanced: machines work on roughly the same number of tasks and work for the same amount of time total

Can you please help me properly formulate the problem? Here is how I started putting it:

- m in M set of machines
- S number of specialties
- [image]
- t in T set of tasks
- [image]
- [image] time to complete task t by machine m
- [image] penalty coefficient for task t for being started with a delay past acceptable time
- X_mt 1 if task t is assigned to machine m 0 otherwise

**objective function:**
Find optimal X_mt such that task are started on time (limit penalty)

[image: Objective function]

**constraints:**

- work duration is balanced through the machines (epsilon being a parameter):

[image: balanced duration]

- number of work item is balanced through the machines (epsilon being a parameter):

[image: balanced number]

- machine selects task for which it specializes (dotproduct m specialty/t characteristics )

[image: specialization]

- minimize makespan

[image: makespan]

- only assign 1 task per machine

[image: singleton]

I am also looking for an algorithm to find some epsilon-optimal solution based on how I relax the workload balancing parameter.

But before I can try to look for an algorithm, I need help to properly formulate the problem.

I've seen example where variance constraints are formulated as the minimization of the difference of upper and lower boundaries but I don't know how to apply it in this case since I have multiple variance constraints.

If this is too much, how would you translate this problem into a Reinforcement Learning one?

Comment: Instead of limiting the variance we often use the range (`max-min`). That is actually linear.

Comment: Understood, how then do you deal with limiting multiple variances?
(max1-min1)+(max2-min2) ?

Comment: I don't understand why you need something like `(max1-min1)+(max2-min2)`

Comment: I dont know how else to deal with minimizing multiple variances.
I posted a more detailed answer to your question (char limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at one of the variance constraints:

[image]

is wrong IMHO. There should be no "for all m".

I rewrite this as:

```
v[m] = sum(t,d[m,t])  for all m 
variance(v) <= eps    (this is a single, scalar constraint)
   
<==>

v[m] = sum(t,d[m,t])  for all m
minv <= v[m]          for all m 
maxv >= v[m]          for all m
maxv - minv <= eps    (different eps. now to limit the bandwidth)
```

- Similar for the other variance constraint
- I don't see a good reason to add things to the objective.
- This is completely linear